Example of a generating polynomial that is not log-concave
Let $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and let $\mu$ be a probability measure over $2^{[n]}$. In a problem I was working on, I wanted to show that a function of the form is log-concave
$$g_\mu(x) = \sum_{S\subseteq [n]} \mu(S) \prod_{i\in S} x_i$$ at least when $x \in [0,1]^n$. After some searching, I came across these notes, which essentially defines the log-concavity of the measure $\mu$ as the condition that $g_\mu$ is concave. This definition suggests to me that the original thing I was trying to prove (that $g_\mu$ is log-concave always) is false. I have a number of interrrelated questions:

Is my interpretation of what the note is saying correct?
Is there a well-known example of a $\mu$ such that $g_\mu$ is not log-concave?
Are there well known sufficient conditions for when $g_\mu$ is log-concave? One that I am currently aware of is that if $\mu$ represents independent binomial outcomes, (i.e., $\mu(S) = \prod_{i\in S} p_i \prod_{j\not\in S} p_j$), then $g_\mu$ is log-concave. But are there ways to generalize something like this?

